Tournament Of Towns Number Theoretic Problem
The following question is taken from the $45$th TOURNAMENT OF TOWNS, Fall Senior O-level paper.

Consider all $100$-digit positive integers such that each decimal digit of
these equals $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \text{or } 7$. How many of these integers are divisible
by $2^{100}$?

I began by considering the general case: $n$-digit numbers such that each of each decimal digit of
these equals $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \text{or } 7$. For $n=1, n=2$, it was clear that the number of integers divisible by $2^{n}$ was $3^{n}$. Checking with code, the pattern holds for $n=3$. Also, I replaced the digits by $[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]$, and the pattern still holds. This suggests that there being 3 even numbers and 3 odd numbers is important, and not the digits themselves. This suggests itself to a proof by induction, but I was unsure how to proceed, since divisibility by $2^n$ does not seem to help with divisibility with respect to $2^{n+1}$.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

I came up with the same idea: $3^1$ are divisible by $2^1$ ($2$, $4$ and $6$). $3^2$ are divisible by $2^2$ ($32$, $52$, $72$, $24$, $44$, $64$, $36$, $56$, $76$). $3^3$ are divisible by $2^3$ via the same method. So you might be right.

A similar induction idea can be found in IMO 2004/6

Following your idea, we proceed inductively.  Suppose the claim is true for $2^n$, and $n-$digit numbers and let $A=\overline {a_n\cdots a_0}$ be a good value for $n+1$.  Let $A'$ denote $\overline {a_{n-1}\cdots a_0}$ so we have $$A=10^{n}a_n+A'\equiv 0 \pmod {2^{n+1}}$$
Since $2^k\,|\,10^k$ we must have $2^n\,|\,A'$ so $A'$ is a good value for $n$.  Thus there are exactly $3^n$ values $A'$ might take.  Fix one of these and let $B'=\frac {A'}{2^n}$.  Of course we have $$5^na_n+B'\equiv 0 \pmod 2\implies a_n=-B'\pmod 2$$
Thus $A'$ determines the parity of $a_n$.  We remark that there are exactly $3$ odd values for $a_n$ and exactly $3$ even values, hence, for any good $A'$ there are exactly $3$ choices for $a_n$, so we are done.

I was writing almost a similar solution. Beat me to it, but nice! +1

The idea of adding an extra digit had crossed my mind, since there are 3 digits of each parity, but I was unable to formalize it. Very pretty solution! +1
